# ASP.NET Core - 2 @model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have problem with binding 2 models in 1 view. Here is my view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee>
@model PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee
```

The `IEnumerable` uses to generate all employees into tables and the other one will be used to add/edit/delete... I already have functionalities on those operator how ever when viewing data I got error.

Is there anyway that I could bind 2 the same model with different function at the same time in 1 view?

Comment: No. Create one model that has both as properties. that way you can access them both via the wrapping model.

Comment: Using a `Tuple` is the simplest way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I could bind 2 the same model with different
>   function at the same time in 1 view?

**No.**

Create one view-model that has both as properties.

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee> Employees { get; set;}
    public PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee Employee { get; set;}
}
```

that way when populated and passed to the view you can access them both via the wrapping model.

```
@model MyViewModel

@foreach(var e in Model.Employees) {
  <p>@e.Property</p>
}

<p>@Model.Employee.Property</p>
```

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, Do you have any idea how to fix this? `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'prjPEMCOLoan.Models.ModelEmployee'.` It seems that I need to create a new instance right? but When I try to create a new instance inside the model it gives me an error...